# QGIS export as SVG, but restrict to full project extent

Tags: qgis, print-composer, svg

I have a project that includes a shapefile of the boundary for the state of Delaware. In the project properties I have set the project to the bounds desired.
[image]

What I want to accomplish is export the desired bounds to svg, but I haven't been able to setup the print layout to only use only the project bounds that I set.

This is what I am doing.

1. Create New Print Layout
2. Add Map
3. Export as SVG.

I need to figure out, how to restrict the svg bounds to only the extent of the project that I have show above, which is:
minLat: 38.45
maxLat: 40.25
minLon: -76.15
maxLon: -75.05

[image]

What am I missing here to set the bounds of the print layout to export to svg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Layout Map Item, set the Extents propreties to the ones you mention:

[image]

To adapt the whole layout to that extent, click on `Resize Layout to Content` in the Layout properties:[image]

Export to SVG:

[image]